# how to build an array in parent and child manner by fetching mysql data using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, parent-child

this is my code where i am fetching my mysql record.

```
$parentChildArr=array();
//mysql query for fetching parent and child record
$selectparentMenu=mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`item_name`,`menu_type`,`parent` FROM `epic_master_menu`"); 

    if(mysql_num_rows($selectparentMenu)>1) {

while($fetchparentMenu=mysql_fetch_array($selectparentMenu)) {
$parentChildArr[]=$fetchparentMenu['id'];
$parentChildArr[]=$fetchparentMenu['item_name'];
$parentChildArr[]=$fetchparentMenu['menu_type'];
$parentChildArr[]=$fetchparentMenu['parent'];
}

var_export($parentChildArr); // exporting or printing arrays
```

// when i export the array i get this output.

```
   array ( 0 => '1', 1 => 'Dashboard', 2 => 'item', 3 => '0',
 4 => '2', 5 => 'Admission', 6 => 'item', 7 => '0', 8 => '3', 
9 => 'Examination', 10 => 'item', 11 => '0', 12 => '4', 
13 => 'CET', 14 => 'item', 15 => '0');
```

but the problem is that i want to build the array like this.

```
  $newarr=array ( 'dataSource' => array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => '1', 
'text' => 'Dashboard', 'expanded' => 'true', 'spriteCssClass' => 'rootfolder', 
'items' => array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => '89', 'text' => 'Users', 
'expanded' => true, 'spriteCssClass' => 'folder', 
'items' => array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => '94', 'text' => 'Users',
 'spriteCssClass' => 'html', ), 1 => array ( 'id' => '94', 
'text' => 'Users', 'spriteCssClass' => 'html', ), 2 => array ( 
'id' => '94', 'text' => 'Users', 'spriteCssClass' => 'image' ) ) ) ) ) ));
```

database table view is...
[image]

i am not getting the logic that how to build the array like $newarr. thank you

Comment: Your both arrays have diffrent values. Please show the expected result using the values in array you are actually getting so that we can relate.

Comment: show more details with database view

Comment: only three values will be changed one is id other one is text and third one is expanded.. if the item have child item then expanded will be true else false

Comment: @Md.SahadatHossain i have added table view please check it out

Comment: @SankalpMishra please check it out gaini have updated it

Comment: The mysql_ functions have been deprecated for quite some time now - you should be using either the mysqli_ functions or PDO. I'd advise you to bear that in mind when evaluating answers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not tested, but you need to defined a structure and then you need to go recursive... so you can check where is the parent entry to my child ...

```
function structure($data){
    return array(
        'id' => $data['id'],
        'item_name' => $data['item_name'],
        'menu_type' => $data['menu_type'],
        'parent' => $data['parent'],
        'expanded' => false,
        'childs' => array()
    );
}

function recursiveImport(&$parent, $data){
    foreach($parent AS $key => $value){
        if($value['id'] == $data['parent']){
            $parent[$key]['childs'][] = structure($data);
            $parent[$key]['expanded'] = true;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            if(count($value['childs']) > 0){
                foreach($value['childs'] AS $key2 => $child){
                    $result = recursiveImport($parent[$key]['childs'][$key2], $data);
                    if($result === true) return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$newarr = array();    
while($fetchparentMenu=mysql_fetch_array($selectparentMenu)) {
    $result = recursiveImport($newarr , $fetchparentMenu);
    if($result === false){
        $newarr[] = structure($fetchparentMenu);
    }
}

//output array
```

array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => '1', 'item_name' => 'Dashboard', 'menu_type' => 'item', 'parent' => '0', 'expanded' => false, 'childs' => array ( ), ), 1 => array ( 'id' => '2', 'item_name' => 'Admission', 'menu_type' => 'item', 'parent' => '0', 'expanded' => false, 'childs' => array ( ), ), 2 => array ( 'id' => '3', 'item_name' => 'Examination', 'menu_type' => 'item', 'parent' => '0', 'expanded' => false, 'childs' => array ( ), ), 3 => array ( 'id' => '4', 'item_name' => 'CET', 'menu_type' => 'item', 'parent' => '0', 'expanded' => false, 'childs' => array ( ), )

Comment: edit some erros, this will not generate the output you wish, but its a nice showcase what you should to do :)

Comment: see the edit page of my post, hope i get all^^, its not a great idea to develop on the textarea from stackoverflow ;)

Comment: i want to ask one last doubt that is my i written my some static array in structure function..

Comment: this structure function is only to build a array for each child / parent menu entry that have the same fields :) ... you can change the names but you need to change the if too:

Comment: if($value['item_name'] == $data['parent']) <- there you access the item_name field of your structure, if its equal the parent node name, the child is adding to the parent :)

Comment: i mean i have another value that is expanded' => 'true will work only if parent has child for example if parent has child then it will get expanded' => 'true and parent will expand

Comment: add after "$value['childs'][] = structure($data);" this line "$value['expanded'] = true;" to set expanded to true if child is added, in the structure array you can set expanded => false :)

Comment: i have added my output result please check it out.. and also after adding the $value['expanded'] = true; nothing works .. array is taking only exapanded false

Comment: i checked the parent value with the item_name value ... you defined in your database that the parent is the id of the parent_entry ... so you need to change "if($value['item_name'] == $data['parent']){" to "if($value['id'] == $data['parent']){" :)

Comment: sorry to distrub u again but still not getting expected result...i have attached my updated output after changes of this "if($value['item_name'] == $data['parent']){" to "if($value['id'] == $data['parent']){"

Comment: ok, my fault, php changes the new created values/variables from foreach not from the given $newarr ... so i have changed it to the hopefully right one :)

Comment: thank you you are really great it works fine but getting an  notices and warning of undefined index and offset of "childs" and id

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
$m=0;
if(mysql_num_rows($selectparentMenu)>1) {

while($fetchparentMenu=mysql_fetch_array($selectparentMenu)) {
$parentChildArr[$m][]=$fetchparentMenu['id'];
$parentChildArr[$m][]=$fetchparentMenu['item_name'];
$parentChildArr[$m][]=$fetchparentMenu['menu_type'];
$parentChildArr[$m][]=$fetchparentMenu['parent'];
$m++;
}
```

Comment: please read the question again then you will get the idea what type of array i want tahnk you